# Nginx Docker Container Healthcheck

Tags: docker, nginx

We have an Nginx container in our Docker application. We are using the following Healthcheck defined as follows in the Dockerfile for the Nginx Container

```
  HEALTHCHECK --interval=60s --timeout=20s CMD service nginx status
```

Is  this sufficient to determine the nginx container healthy? Or should we using some other script for nginx containers here?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by „healthy” specifically?

Comment: Able to receive requests and forward them. We don't really want to test the downstream node app as that has its own healthcheck.

Comment: You may include a configuration so that nginx responds with a code 200 to a specific url and head request. Then use that url in the health check. It would be light weight and would indicate that the container can serve clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your health definition. You may check if nginx is listening on the TCP port, if nginx response contains a required string, app check (for example login/logout) of the app, which is served by nginx, ...

Comment: we don't want to test the downstream app

Comment: You don't need to test app. It can be own nginx endpoint, which will return response.